# Split a string that taking string and integer values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I want to split a string that taking both string and integer values like (Cmp_12).
I want to use them in Separately.

Comment: Can you provide a fuller sample of what the input string might look like?

Comment: And please explain how this is relevant to SQL Server 2005. Are you using values from the database? Do you want to convert it with inline sql in vb.net? provide som more information and maybe an example as @Fredrik pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a known Sign between the two Items you want then you my use

```
Dim myString as string = "Item1_Item2"
Dim MyItems() as string = split(myString,"_")
Dim ItemA as string = MyItems(0)
Dim ItemB as string = MyItems(1)
```

This is one way to get your two Items in a string
In case you know what type is the Items then you may use the

```
Cint(MyItems(x))
Cbool(MyItems(x))
```

Or what ever conversion you like 
I really don't know if I'm close to your question

Comment: So can i use these two items separately, if i cann then how to use in if conditions?

Comment: @Ritu, If ItemA .... then [do something] end if. Or you may use If ItemA =, <=, <>, [of somehting] and ItemB =, <=, <>, [of somehting] then [do something] end if. And please remember to vote the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Regular Expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx)

For numbers: `[\d]+`  will match one or more numeric digits.

For the text: `[a-z]+` will match one or more letters in the range a-z. You could use the `/i` operator to make this bit case-insensitive.

Doing a `.match` call on each string twice (first for the number test and then for the text test) will get you what you're after. There is a more elegant way of doing this with `matchgroups`, but this will get you started.

Try this interactive Regular expression tester - its very useful: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 0):

using [split](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php) function like

```
var str = "camp_12";
var str_array = str.split("_");
alert(str_array[0]+" "+str_array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server** version using [left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), [right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [charindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

```
declare @s varchar(50) = 'Cmp_12'

select  
  left(@s, charindex('_', @s, 0)-1),
  right(@s, len(@s)-charindex('_', @s, 0))
```

Comment: Yes this is another very good way to get the substrings, provited that you know the length of each one.

Comment: @Lefteris - You do not need to know the length of the string, only the max length, in this I choose 50. You do however need to know the delimiter. `len` gives you the length of the string and `charindex` gives you the position of `_`.

Comment: Yes your right but when i say Length I mean the use of "Left"or "Right" there you need to know the length of each one, in order to exclude the other, how long will be the piece you will take it back.